# Compare and Return Data in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, vba

what function or vba can return the picture shown below.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fX702.png)
I have tried vloopup, match etc, and i can get col B in the "Return" Column, but the problem is I do not know how to add the column C at one time.

Comment: Please describe what you want in your question. You picture doesn't give me any clue as to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,$C$1:$C$6,0)),"",A1)

Comment: the above is the formula im currently using to compare column a and column c.

Comment: i want to compare two columns (Col A and Col C) so that Column B will return the same number that both A and C have. However, Col D is related to Col C, so what I am trying to do is to add relevant number in Col D in Column B... Don't know if it is more clear.. Please tell me if you still confused and I can make another picture to explain it. Thank you!

Comment: I have added another picture to explain it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do it:

```
=IFERROR(A2&INDEX(D$2:D$7,MATCH(A2,C$2:C$7,0)),"")
```

Comment: Looking at your new example, if you want to add the `,`, then just use this: `=IFERROR(A2&","&INDEX(D$2:D$7,MATCH(A2,C$2:C$7,0)),"")`